# May 12, 2015 linked in Developer Program changes

Tags: linkedin-api, profile

I am getting basic profile fields information by using 
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=" + url (linkedin profile url). 
After May 12, 2015 linked in Developer Program changes is there any problem to access basic profile fields with above url.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for LinkedIn support

Answer (score -2):

Per [Changes to our Developer Program: Adam Trachtenberg February 12, 2015][1]

> Starting on May 12, 2015, we will be limiting the open APIs to only support the following uses:
>
> Allowing members to represent their professional identity via their LinkedIn profile using our Profile API.
>
> Enabling members to post certifications directly to their LinkedIn profile with our Add to Profile tools.
>
> Enabling members to share professional content to their LinkedIn network from across the Web leveraging our Share API.
>
> Enabling companies to share professional content to LinkedIn with our Company API.
>
> All other APIs will require developers to become a member of one of our partnership programs.